# Unresolved Reference with Variables that have already been defined?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a program that requires me to use coordinates. I established 4 different values for coordinates RoiX1, RoiY1, RoiX2, and RoiY2. I also have other values that have been defined that return the same message.

**Here is the code for the variables I mentioned earlier that returns this message:**

```
                RoiX1 = int(db.child("coordinates").child("Xa1").get().val()
                RoiY1 = int(db.child("coordinates").child("Ya1").get().val()
                RoiX2 = int(db.child("coordinates").child("Xa2").get().val()
                RoiY2 = int(db.child("coordinates").child("Ya2").get().val()
                PreArea = abs((RoiX1-RoiX2)*(RoiY1-RoiY2))
```

For the PreArea, every variable in that equation returns `Unresolved reference ''`

**Here is another example block of code:**

```
                    rects = []
                    success, img = cap.read()
                    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=0.4)
                    bbox = list(bbox)
                    confs = list(np.array(confs).reshape(1, -1)[0])
                    confs = list(map(float, confs))
                    indicies = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bbox, confs, 0.2, 0.1)
```

**Here is where these messages show up after the above variables:**

```
if len(classIds) != 0:
    i = indicies[0][0]
    box = bbox[i]
    rects.append(box)
    object = tracker.update(rects)
    X = object[1][0][0]
    Y = object[1][0][1]
    W = object[1][0][2]
    H = object[1][0][3]
    X2 = (X + W)
    Y2 =(Y + H)
    if abs(RoiX1 - X) <= ROI_dif and abs(RoiY1 - Y) <= ROI_dif abs(RoiX2 - X2) <= ROI_dif and abs(RoiY2 - Y2) <= ROI_dif:
    Detected_ClassId = classIds[0][0]
```

After the if statement, all variables mentioned become underlined with the message.

Here, the variable bbox, indicies, and rects and all other variables no matter where, remain unresolved. Any help as to why this may occur in Python is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: This is hardly a reproducible example. It's impossible for us to help you if all we're given is some code with no context.

Comment: @PaulM. How can I make this kind of example reproducible? It would require me to post a lot of code.

Comment: It may not be the cause of your problem but you are missing closing braces on your Roi lines.

Comment: @EdgarBabajanyan How much is "a lot"? Also, what IDE are you using? This doesn't seem to be a vanilla-Python exception.

Comment: @PaulM. I am using PyCharm. I just added more code that gives me the same error.

Comment: @EdgarBabajanyan Have you tried `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`?

Comment: @EdgarBabajanyan In any case it is a PyCharm issue, not a Python issue. You can share a GitHub link if you wish, but I don't think it would be useful because I don't use PyCharm, so I won't run into the same errors. Searching for "PyCharm variable unresolved reference" yields many search results in any search engine. I would try solutions you find online until you find one that works.

Comment: @PaulM. I fixed it for the top 4 variables by adding the parenthesis necessary at the variables.

Comment: @EdgarBabajanyan Alright, I'll bite - if you share a GitHub link I'll take a look. You could also just edit your question and post the entire code. ~200 lines is not that much.

Comment: @PaulM. I do not have any more errors with those variables but now I have a strange Python error with an if statement. Maybe you could take a look? I added the entire program to the post.

Comment: You're missing an `and` in the middle of the if statement. `abs(RoiY1 - Y) <= ROI_dif abs(RoiX2 - X2) <= ROI_dif` should be `abs(RoiY1 - Y) <= ROI_dif **and** abs(RoiX2 - X2) <= ROI_dif`

Comment: Ah yes you were right. My bad. Simple mistake.